# Cloning two select2 blocks

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I use plugin Select2 for my select blocks. And I have some troubles with cloning. Second problem - In cloning selections I can't select the item that was selected in the previous blocks.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var Count = 1;

    $(".entry").children("select").select2({});
    $(".btn-add").click(function () {
        $(".entry")
            .children("select").each(function () {
                $(this)
            // call destroy to revert the changes made by Select2
                .select2("destroy")
                .removeAttr('data-live-search')
                .removeAttr('data-select2-id')
                .removeAttr('aria-hidden')
                .removeAttr('tabindex');
        });
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var controlForm = $('.controls fieldset:first-child'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

        newEntry.find('input').val('');
        controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
            .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
            .html('<div id="rectangle"></div>');

        $(".entry").children("select").each(function () {
            $(this).select2({});
        });

    }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
    {

        $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();
        e.preventDefault();

        $(".entry").children("select").each(function () {
            $(this).select2({});
        });
        return false;
    });
 });
```

Few days ago I solved the problem of copying one such block. But today I'm trying to use same code for cloning 2 blocks and I get this - in first row I take 1 block without this plugin and 1 with them, at second both items have it. When I try to clone again last row have 2 original and 2 duplicated blocks.

The result I need is correct cloning of elements and the ability to select any item in each row

Update: I attach examples of work: [This is default situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwOUK.jpg), [This happens when we clicking 1 time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9FNN.jpg), [Clicking two time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0BEW.jpg), [Clicking five times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggtye.jpg)
This code working for [one select like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1l9q.jpg)

Comment: looks like you have two different click bindings for `.btn-add`, also i dont get this line `newEntry.find('input').val('');` select is not input, maybe an minimal playable example could help

Comment: First `.btn-add` function destroys plugin from all selects, second - cloning row and then initialize plugin for all selects. It works for 1 select. What about input row... I don't care about it. Nothing happens when I hide this.